# when getting images from firebase firestore it doesn't load quickly

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get my doctors collection info using streambuilder, every doctor has his info including his picture that I uploaded previously in firebase storage and inserts it's URL into firestore as string, all info downloaded well except pictures there is always delay before they show up in UI(they aren't being cached) or sometimes they're not uploaded . is it because i'm not getting them from firebase storage directly?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('doctors').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: KInActiveColor,
                ),
              );
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }

            return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: false,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: snapshot.data.docs
                      .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    final doctorname = data['name'];
                    final doctorpic = data['drpic'];
                    final doctormajor = data['major'];
                    final doctordetails = data['details'];
                    return doctorCard(
                      name: doctorname ?? 'default value',
                      pic: doctorpic ?? 'default value',
                      major: doctormajor ?? 'default value',
                      details: doctordetails ?? 'default value',
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              );
            });
          },
        )
```

**here is my firebase firestore**
[image]

**here is firebase Storage**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior. You can use a package to cache these images in the local storage. After downloading for the first time it will not download pictures again.

[cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: wondering if there is a similar thing with web using vuejs? cause I had the similar problem before

Comment: Not sure about vuejs as I am not the developer of it.